# Convert a .sav file to .csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scipy

I want to convert the contents of *.sav file into a *.csv file in Python. I have written the following lines of code to access the details of variables in *.sav file. Now, I am not clear on how I can write the accessed variable data to a .csv file with headers

```
import scipy.io as spio
on2file = 'ON2_2015_112m_220415.sav'
on2data = spio.readsav(on2file, python_dict=True, verbose=True)
```

Following is the result when I run the above lines of the code:

```
IDL Save file is compressed
 -> expanding to /var/folders/z4/r3844ql123jgkq1ztdr4jxrm0000gn/T/tmpVE_Iz6.sav
--------------------------------------------------
Date: Mon Feb 15 20:41:02 2016
User: zhangy1
Host: augur
--------------------------------------------------
Format: 9
Architecture: x86_64
Operating System: linux
IDL Version: 7.0
--------------------------------------------------
Successfully read 11 records of which:
 - 7 are of type VARIABLE
 - 1 are of type TIMESTAMP
 - 1 are of type NOTICE
 - 1 are of type VERSION
--------------------------------------------------
Available variables:
 - saved_data [<class 'numpy.recarray'>]
 - on2_grid_smooth [<type 'numpy.ndarray'>]
 - d_lat [<type 'numpy.float32'>]
 - on2_grid [<type 'numpy.ndarray'>]
 - doy [<type 'str'>]
 - year [<type 'str'>]
 - d_lon [<type 'numpy.float32'>]
--------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone suggest me with how I can write all the variable data to a .csv file?

I want to write the variables (year, doy, d_lon, d_lat, on2_grid, on2_grid_smooth) to a CSV or ASCII file is supposed to look in the following manner:

```
longitude, latitude, on2_grid, on2_grid_smooth   # header 
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0              
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 
0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
.....
```

The shape of "on2_grid" and "on2_grid_smooth" variables is the same and is (101, 202). Both are of the type "numpy.ndarray".

Comment: Which variable(s) do you want to write?  What is the csv supposed to look like?  We should also know the shape and dtype for the array(s) that you want to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem by changing the requisite output format and here is my code:

```
import scipy.io as spio
import numpy as np
import csv

on2file = 'ON2_2016_112m_220415.sav'   # i/p file
outfile = 'ON2_2016_112m_220415.csv'   # o/p file

# Read i/p file
s = spio.readsav(on2file, python_dict=True, verbose=True)

# Creating Grid
#d_lat = s["d_lat"]
#d_lon = s["d_lon"]
lat = np.arange(-90,90,1.78218)  # (101,)
lon = np.arange(-180,180,1.78218)     # (202,)
ylat,xlon = np.meshgrid(lat,lon)

on2grid = np.asarray(s["on2_grid"])
on2gridsmooth = np.asarray(s["on2_grid_smooth"])

nrows = len(on2grid)
ncols = len(on2grid[0])

xlon_grid = xlon.reshape(nrows*ncols,1)
ylat_grid = ylat.reshape(nrows*ncols,1)
on2grid_new = on2grid.reshape(nrows*ncols,1)
on2gridsmooth_new = on2gridsmooth.reshape(nrows*ncols,1)

# Concatenation
allgriddata = np.concatenate((xlon_grid, ylat_grid, on2grid_new, on2gridsmooth_new),axis=1)

# Writing o/p file
f_handle = file(outfile,'a')
np.savetxt(f_handle,allgriddata,delimiter=",",fmt='%0.3f',header="longitude, latitude, on2_grid, on2_grid_smooth")
f_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, you can import SPSS files very easily into Python using `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_spss("input_file.sav")
```

And then you can export the data with the [`.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method:

```py
df.to_csv("output_file.csv", index=False)
```

If you only need to export certain columns, you can specify that too:

```py
df[["column_a", "column_b"]].to_csv("output_file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: That's a great answer, but note that one needs to install pyreadstat first.
`pip install pyreadstat`

Comment: important - pyreadstate library is needed first.

Answer (score 1):

The column of latitude and longitude in the extracted files using your code looks interchanged. Further the latitude scale ranges from 0 to 180 (not +90 0 -90)) ...whether  the 0 starts from the top.  Pl. comment.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this solution uses R instead of python, but it is really simple and works well.

```
library(foreign)
write.table(read.spss("inFile.sav"), file="outFile.csv", quote = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on it and, for the moment, this is my 'poor' solution:

First I import module savReaderWriter to convert .sav file into structured array
Second I import module numpy to convert structured array into csv:

```
import savReaderWriter 
import numpy as np

reader_np = savReaderWriter.SavReaderNp("infile.sav")
array = reader_np.to_structured_array("outfile.dat") 
np.savetxt("outfile2.csv", array, delimiter=",")
reader_np.close()
```

The problem is that I lose name atributes during conversion. I will try to solve the problem.