# Convert SPSS file to CSV and read to create Data Table

Tags: r, csv, datatable, spss, crosstab

I have an SPSS file from which I am creating a data table using R script. But the problem is it's taking a bit of time to load the data table. I want to convert the SPSS(.sav) file into CSV file first and then read the CSV file to create a data table. So far I have tried multiple codes but that didn't work out properly. 
Here's the code which I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532250/convert-a-sav-file-to-csv-file-in-python).

Comment: look into the haven package

Comment: I have gone through that as well but the function includes reading an SPSS file and writing into other files. I may be wrong but I think it doesn't let us convert the SPSS file into CSV file and then read that CSV file to create a Data Table.

Comment: Why do you need to create a CSV?

Comment: I am creating cross tabs so I need to create a CSV file from SPSS file which is of large size and takes time to load so, to minimize the file size and create a data table which doesn't take too much time to load I want to convert the SPSS file to CSV first .I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think foreign package in r can be used to solve this problem.

```
library(foreign)
write.table(read.spss("inFile.sav"), file="outFile.csv", quote = TRUE, sep = ",")
```