# Why is Jupyter using a column's values to populate column names?

Tags: jupyter, spss

I'm using an SPSS .sav file that has typical column names like name, type, width, and so forth. The 'names' column labels the rows m1, I1, I2, etc.

Here's the Jupyter notebook:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kzYf.jpg

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_spss('./Data.sav')
df.head()
```

As you can see, the column names are the entries for 'Name':
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yVUU.jpg
I.e., rather than 'name', 'type', 'width' as column names, there are the values for 'name': m1, I1, I2, etc.

I'm quite new to Jupyter and SPSS and have no idea where to start.

EDIT:
Following Rahul Singh's suggestions, I've added `header=None`, though read_spss() doesn't seem to recognize the argument.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_spss('./Data.sav',header=None)
df.head()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-77d006c914c9> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df = pd.read_spss('./Data_ANQAR_Wave39.sav',header=None)
      3 df.head()

TypeError: read_spss() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'

`
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, rather than pics

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue is not with jupyter it's with pandas (we should not say it issue :) )

```
Usually when you read data from any file(.csv, .txt etc) and header (column names) is is not available in it then pandas will automaticly take first row as header.
To get rid of this problem you can provide `header=None`
```

Code :

```
import savReaderWriter 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Convert .sav file into .csv
reader_np = savReaderWriter.SavReaderNp("Data.sav")
array = reader_np.to_structured_array("outfile.dat") 
np.savetxt("Data.csv", array, delimiter=",")
reader_np.close()

# Read .csv file without header
df = pd.read_spss("Data.csv",header=None)
df.head()
```

Comment: Actually your data is in .sav file and `pd.read_spss()` doesn't support `header` attribute. So please try to convert your .sav file to .csv and then you can use `header=None` with `pd.read_csv()`. I found this solution at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532250/convert-a-sav-file-to-csv-file-in-python) which was answered by Alejandro JCuesta

Comment: Please try this, and let us know. In case of any issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at in SPSS is not the data (data editor) but the metadata (variable view) which shows characteristics for your columns rather than the data itself. Pandas is reading the data correctly, in SPSS switch to the Data Editor to see what I mean.